# subset of real axis

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

I tried this problem from a shortlist of IMO problems :
Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ be distinct positive integers and let $M$ be a set of $n-1$ positive integers not containing $s=a_1+...+a_n$. A grasshopper is to jump along the real axis, starting at the point $0$ and making $n$ jumps to the right with lengths $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ in some order. Prove that the order can be chosen in such a way that the grasshopper never lands on any point in $M$.

I tried induction but this seems to be a combinatorial problem.

Comment: Use `\ldots` and `\cdots` instead of `...` to get a properly spaced ellipsis on the baseline and vertically centred, respectively.

Comment: [Here](https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/IMO-2009-notes.pdf), on page 9, you will find a solution to the problem; see also here [Hard Imo Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658297).